# Pulumi runtime can't find pulumi library

Tags: python, conda, pulumi, pulumi-python

I keep hitting this problem where the `pulumi` CLI tool runs, but whenever I try to do anything with it like `pulumi up` or `pulumi preview` it gives me this error that it can't find its own library:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/.pulumi/bin/pulumi-language-python-exec", line 16, in <module>
        import pulumi
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pulumi'
```

The last time I solved this I realized the root cause was that I'm using conda to manage my python environments.  The tool suggests `pip install pulumi` which doesn't really work because then it'll just complain about `No module named 'pulumi_aws'` etc.

I've forgotten how I got around the problem, so I'm putting the question up here so when I figure it out I'll have a good place to post the solution.  Or maybe somebody has knows the answer.

Comment: Is the path to the Pulumi binary on your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably more than one way to skin this cat, but here's a way that works for me to fix this.  It's to make sure you're using a pulumi-specific `venv` for the pulumi code.

In your project's `Pulumi.yaml` make sure the runtime is explicitly configured to use a venv:

```
runtime:
  name: python
  options:
    virtualenv: venv
```

Then running `pulumi preview` will instantiate the `venv` directory with at least some of the stuff you need.  Likely not all of it though.  You might still get `ModuleNotFoundError`, but now you can fix them by running commands like:

```
venv/bin/pip install pulumi
venv/bin/pip install pulumi_aws
# etc
```

At this point, the pulumi CLI will use the venv, and be able to find the libraries it needs.

Comment: For me i had to remove the `options` setting as i use poetry, and direnv to automatically activate the virtualenv.

Comment: @NicolasKarolak Im also using poetry and having error: "failed to load language plugin python: no language plugin 'pulumi-language-python' found in the workspace or on your $PATH" did you see this before? how did you fix it? thank you.

Comment: @Zucoa i don't recall having this issue. But it looks like your venv is missing the `pulumi` Python package.